# Composer different PHP versions and common PSR

Tags: php, linux, composer-php

There are tons of answers on different PHP versions and Composer. But none seems to address my issue.

I have to switch back from PHP 8 to PHP 7 on my Ubuntu for a certain project.

No problem so far - I have different PHP versions installed and switching between PHP versions works easily:

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.4
update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.4
```

Then I run `composer update` in my project folder:

```
php7.4 /usr/bin/composer update
```

I get the following error when using composer:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in 
/usr/share/php/Psr/Log/LoggerInterface.php on line 30
```

The problem would seem to be that the PSR library is PHP 8 only.

It would seem I need different `/usr/share/php/` locations for my libraries - a common folder will not do the job, as the libraries in this folder will need to change with the PHP version.

I have no idea where `/usr/share/php/` is configured - nor why composer uses this PSR stuff. At all. I think I need to install different composer version as well?

In reply to comments:

- My composer version is 2.4.1
- the "second error message" was copy/past chunk. Sorry - removed.
- `apt-cache rdepends php-psr-log` lists composer among others
- renaming /usr/share/php/Psr result into this error: Failed opening required 'Psr/Log/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/php/Composer/XdebugHandler/autoload.php
- I tried to install the PSR log dependency in my project (`php8.1 composer require psr/log:^1.0 --ignore-platform-req=all --no-update`). Then I ran `php7.4 composer update` again, but still the same error with line 30.

Comment: From my ignorance... Is there an `update-alternatives` option for Composer as well?

Comment: Composer is a phar which internally includes all the vendor dependencies. Those dependencies are using php 8, that's why you get parsing errors when running composer using php 7.4.

Comment: Use `update-alternatives --config php`. It queries you with the available versions and might work better than doing each executable manually. BTW: You can call composer with different interpreters without doing that dance.

Comment: Why are the PSR libraries installed as shared libraries, and not as project dependencies?

Comment: You should mention which version of composer you are using, for completeness. Although latest composer supports PHP ^7.2 | ^8 anyway.

Comment: `/usr/share/php` does not sound like something that Composer should use? And: "Obviously I need different /usr/share/php/ locations for my libraries" - why is that obvious?

Comment: @NicoHaase - because I get an error for PHP8 code running in PHP7 - so these libraries are PHP version dependend and should be switchable, right?

Comment: Why not install them properly in your project to be switchable? Or did you switch them through any way which you haven't shared? `update-alternatives` won't magically install new packages

Comment: "renaming /usr/share/php/Psr result into this error" - why not remove the package and install it through your application's dependencies instead?

Comment: @NicoHaase - thank you, but did not work (see edit of question above)

Comment: Why not remove the package that interfers properly, or even inspect why this is getting included every time?

Comment: @NicoHaase - this has nothing to do with my project. It has been installed with composer and is a dependency. I can't uninstall it. Tried to remove it and install locally without any luck. "Inspect" sounds good, I am happy for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is installing Composer with apt.

You shouldn't do that, as it will install its own dependencies system-wide. For example, PHP is a Composer dependency, or these PSR libraries you mention in your question.

Remove composer with the system's package manager, and install Composer directly using [these instructions](https://getcomposer.org/download/).

Do not install the PSR dependencies in your project unless you need them. For the looks of it, you don't, it's simply they were installed by apt.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, according to the [Composer's documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#system-requirements):

> Composer, in its latest version, requires PHP 7.2.5 to run. A long-term-support version (2.2.x) still offers support for PHP 5.3.2+ in case you are stuck with a legacy PHP version.

So, as long as you are on version 7.2.5 or higher, you should be good. Secondly, I also manage several projects myself where the PHP version varies. I have created some aliases in my Fish shell to ensure that I am using Composer with the correct PHP version (otherwise, it might pull the wrong dependencies), and these aliases perform the same function as what you did manually:

```bash
alias composer5="php5.6 $(which composer)"
alias composer7="php7.4 $(which composer)"
alias composer8="php8.1 $(which composer)"
```

I have never encountered problems with this approach, especially since `composer` is a self-contained PHAR archive and does not require any external dependencies.

Now, regarding the issues with `/usr/share/php/Psr/Log/LoggerInterface.php`, this arises from the system-wide include path, causing this location to be included at runtime because package was installed when you was using PHP 8, so code is using PHP 8 features, and now, when you try to use PHP 7 and that package is pulled, it causes syntax errors.

A quick [search on the Ubuntu package database](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=Psr%2FLog%2FLoggerInterface.php&mode=exactfilename&suite=kinetic&arch=any) reveals that this likely comes from `php-psr-log` package, indicating that you probably installed some PHP packages using APT, which led to this dependency being installed. I always discourage people from installing any PHP application from a Debian package unless it's the only PHP package/application installed (like in a container/VPS, etc.). This is always a source of significant issues. The only things you should have installed are the PHP interpreter and perhaps the composer PHAR; that's it. Any other dependency should be a local package dependency kept in its `vendor/` folder.

Here are my recommended steps to check which PHP packages you have installed using APT:

```bash
dpkg -l "*php*" | grep ii
```

This command will only list packages that contain `php` word in the name (so for instance, the `mediawiki` package wont's how up even if you have it), but if you see more than just PHP itself, consider removing them. Also you can check what really depends on the packages you find suspicious using `apt-cache`, i.e:

```bash
apt-cache rdepends php-psr-log
```

**HINT** you can look for packages depending on the `php` interpreter too.

And if removal of these `/usr/share/php/` files is not possible at the moment, there are some options I think are worth considering:

1. tweak PHP at runtime, ensuring that `/usr/share/php/` is not in your include path.
2. Move (temporarily) these files away so it won't be used at runtime. But that might break other packages, so careful.
3. reinstall the packages you must have installed globally using PHP 7. That will make them still work with PHP 8 (unless there are bugs) and with PHP 7.

But again. do not have anything installed globally.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. It looks like my composer installation has a dependency on /usr/shares/php/Psr (see edit at bottom of my question)